# openssl CMS with ECDH EnvelopedData

Tags: cryptography, openssl, elliptic-curve

I am playing with openssl 1.0.2a - specifically CMS support for ECC. 
As a test I am doing a simple encrypt and decrypt.
I gave an RSA example as a known good working example / sanity test.
The ECC example fails.

Any ideas? TIA.

```
./openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015

echo -n 12345678123456781234567812345678 > sess.txt # 32 byte plaintext

#RSA works
./openssl genrsa -out rsa.key 2048
./openssl req -x509 -new -key rsa.key -out rsa.crt
./openssl cms -encrypt -in sess.txt -out rsaencsess.bin -outform PEM rsa.crt
./openssl cms -decrypt -in rsaencsess.bin -out rsadecsess.txt -inform PEM -inkey rsa.key
#AOK.

#EC fails
  ./openssl ecparam -name prime192v1 -genkey -out ecc.key
  ./openssl req -x509 -new -key ecc.key -out ecc.crt
  ./openssl cms -encrypt -in sess.txt -out encsess.bin -outform PEM ecc.crt
  ./openssl cms -decrypt -in encsess.bin -out decsess.txt -inform PEM -inkey ecc.key
Error decrypting CMS structure
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:529:
```

Comment: Interesting, what does the output look like? Don't worry, I'm not going to decrypt a ciphertext protected by a 192 bit key :P

Comment: OpenSSL's Steve Henson resolved it as follows: "RSA can decrypt without knowing the certificate but currently EC cannot. So try including the option -recip ecc.crt when you decrypt."

Comment: You can add that as an answer. Its a bit strange though, both the param ident and the public key are part of the private key structure.

Comment: yes - that's what threw me. I guess it's because the support for EC was just added in 1.0.2. And thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Small note: CLI is (borderline) off topic on StackOverflow. Usually these kind of questions are better asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). It's borderline as shell scripting is definitely programming, making questions about bash scripts for instance very on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL's Steve Henson resolved it as follows: "RSA can decrypt without knowing the certificate but currently EC cannot. So try including the option -recip ecc.crt when you decrypt

this now works:

```
./openssl ecparam -name prime192v1 -genkey -out ecc.key
./openssl req -x509 -new -key ecc.key -out ecc.crt
./openssl cms -encrypt -in sess.txt -out encsess.bin -outform PEM ecc.crt
./openssl cms -decrypt -in encsess.bin -out decsess.txt -inform PEM -inkey ecc.key -recip ecc.crt # NOTE "-recip ecc.crt" is currently required else it won't work!
```