# CMS_encrypt using ECDH key

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

I'm trying to implement CMS encrypt using ECDH keys. Ref [openssl CMS with ECDH EnvelopedData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280688/openssl-cms-with-ecdh-envelopeddata) The command line works flawlessly but my program is giving an error -

```
Error Encrypting Data
140508524291744:error:2E06507D:CMS routines:CMS_add1_recipient_cert:not supported for this key type:cms_env.c:210:
```

In code below, recip.pem was created using steps here [openssl CMS with ECDH EnvelopedData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280688/openssl-cms-with-ecdh-envelopeddata)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/cms.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    CMS_ContentInfo *cms1 = NULL;
    BIO *in = NULL, *out = NULL, *tbio = NULL;
    X509 *rcert = NULL;
    int ret = 1;
    int flags = CMS_STREAM;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    tbio = BIO_new_file("recip.pem", "r");
    if (!tbio)
        goto err;

    rcert = PEM_read_bio_X509(tbio, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (!rcert)
        goto err;

    in = BIO_new_file("encr.txt", "r");
    flags |= CMS_PARTIAL;
    cms1 = CMS_encrypt(NULL, in, EVP_des_ede3_cbc(), flags);

    CMS_RecipientInfo *ri;
    ri = CMS_add1_recipient_cert(cms1, rcert, flags);
    if (!ri)
        goto err;

    if(!CMS_final(cms1, in, NULL, flags))
        goto err;

    if (!cms1)
        goto err;

    out = BIO_new_file("cms1.pem", "w");
    if(!out)
        goto err;

    if(!PEM_write_bio_CMS_stream(out, cms1, in, flags))
        goto err;

    ret = 0;

err:
    if (ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Encrypting Data\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }

    if (cms1)
        CMS_ContentInfo_free(cms1);
    if (rcert)
        X509_free(rcert);

    if (in)
        BIO_free(in);
    if (out)
        BIO_free(out);
    if (tbio)
        BIO_free(tbio);

    return ret; 
}
```

The documentation states ECC keys are not supported yet the commandline cms app is able to do it without a problem. I stepped through the cms app but am unable to figure out what I'm doing differently. Also tried the cms_enc.c from the demos folder but that does not handle ecc keys as well.

What I expect to my program to do is

```
> openssl cms -encrypt -aes256 -in "x.txt" -out "y.bin" -outformat PEM ecc.crt
> openssl asn1parse -dump -in "y.bin"

    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 855 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim:  OBJECT            :pkcs7-envelopedData
   15:d=1  hl=4 l= 840 cons:  cont [ 0 ]
   19:d=2  hl=4 l= 836 cons:   SEQUENCE
   23:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim:    INTEGER           :02
   26:d=3  hl=4 l= 379 cons:    SET
   30:d=4  hl=4 l= 375 cons:     cont [ 1 ]
   34:d=5  hl=2 l=   1 prim:      INTEGER           :03
   37:d=5  hl=3 l= 151 cons:      cont [ 0 ]
   40:d=6  hl=3 l= 148 cons:       cont [ 1 ]
   43:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 cons:        SEQUENCE
   45:d=8  hl=2 l=   7 prim:         OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey
   54:d=7  hl=3 l= 134 prim:        BIT STRING
      0000 - 00 04 00 3e 4c 80 5b bb-10 ff 83 30 33 1f 44 ab   ...>L.[....03.D.
      0010 - ad 2c a2 9d a9 5a 19 5f-8e 5a dc 30 a2 4d f5 19   .,...Z._.Z.0.M..
      0020 - 51 49 e6 cb ff 63 08 e7-87 e8 d3 66 60 f5 0f 67   QI...c.....f`..g
      0030 - c1 94 3a aa b9 88 3c 7c-5c cd 5a cd 4e f2 5f ba   ..:...<|\.Z.N._.
      0040 - 15 05 0d bc 01 be 6c 2c-32 fd b1 3d d1 d1 52 f8   ......l,2..=..R.
      0050 - e0 43 a5 03 25 05 2a 63-32 47 d9 e6 15 71 75 d0   .C..%.*c2G...qu.
      0060 - 5b 45 ca f5 db 91 e2 68-4c 65 29 1c 6d c3 1f f1   [E.....hLe).m...
      0070 - 3a e4 55 78 1b dd 95 b5-bd 24 06 31 34 fa 26 c5   :.Ux.....$.14.&.
      0080 - 52 8f c9 24 37 4c                                 R..$7L
  191:d=5  hl=2 l=  23 cons:      SEQUENCE
  193:d=6  hl=2 l=   6 prim:       OBJECT            :1.3.132.1.11.1
  201:d=6  hl=2 l=  13 cons:       SEQUENCE
  203:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim:        OBJECT            :id-aes256-wrap
  214:d=7  hl=2 l=   0 prim:        NULL
  216:d=5  hl=3 l= 190 cons:      SEQUENCE
  219:d=6  hl=3 l= 187 cons:       SEQUENCE
  222:d=7  hl=3 l= 142 cons:        SEQUENCE
  225:d=8  hl=3 l= 128 cons:         SEQUENCE
  228:d=9  hl=2 l=  11 cons:          SET
  230:d=10 hl=2 l=   9 cons:           SEQUENCE
  232:d=11 hl=2 l=   3 prim:            OBJECT            :countryName
  237:d=11 hl=2 l=   2 prim:            PRINTABLESTRING   :US
  241:d=9  hl=2 l=  19 cons:          SET
  243:d=10 hl=2 l=  17 cons:           SEQUENCE
  245:d=11 hl=2 l=   3 prim:            OBJECT            :stateOrProvinceName
  250:d=11 hl=2 l=  10 prim:            UTF8STRING        :California
  ## other cert params ##
  356:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim:         INTEGER           :FEEAB1D7F247D77B
  367:d=7  hl=2 l=  40 prim:        OCTET STRING
      0000 - d5 fd 5c 37 ac 0b b7 ad-07 b7 42 38 5a 3e a5 bc   ..\7......B8Z>..
      0010 - 5e eb 1f bf a4 b9 63 bb-6d 58 87 a5 3c 96 34 68   ^.....c.mX..<.4h
      0020 - 55 26 4e 63 f0 16 92 0a-                          U&Nc....
  409:d=3  hl=4 l= 446 cons:    SEQUENCE
  413:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
  424:d=4  hl=2 l=  29 cons:     SEQUENCE
  426:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 prim:      OBJECT            :aes-256-cbc
  437:d=5  hl=2 l=  16 prim:      OCTET STRING
      0000 - 82 cd 6e 4b 7a 2a bc 59-63 c0 55 a3 bb b1 9a e6   ..nKz*.Yc.U.....
  455:d=4  hl=4 l= 400 prim:     cont [ 0 ]
```

Comment: I seem to recall there are some theoretical problems with using DH params like this (but I could be wrong). Here, "like this" means encrypting one message under one data encryption key, and then encrypting the data encryption key under multiple user keys. I *think* that's why there are no multiparty ECIES-like schemes. Maybe you should hop over to [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and see if its a valid thing to do. (I wish I could find that paper I was reading about it... It sucks getting old. You start forgetting things...).

Comment: I think the crypto is ok. Have added output from equivalent operations done using openssl's cms utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The command line works flawlessly but my program is giving an error
```

Did you build a local copy of the `openssl` binary, as the link you refer to assumes? If so, then the different behaviour is most likely caused by different versions of the openssl (given that you link your example code against system libraries). Support for EC was added quite recently; my system OpenSSL version **1.0.1f** reports the same error as you show, while locally installed version **1.0.2a** successfully encrypts with an EC key.

So if you need your binary to work with EC keys, either install a newer OpenSSL on your system, or link the binary statically against locally-build OpenSSL libraries (libssl and libcrypto).

Comment: I had built a new openssl and symlinked to it - thereby mistakenly assuming that the openssl libraries had also been linked to.